# How to allow drag UIView (PanGesture..) just in some area

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I need drag UIView via `PanGestureRecognizer` (I know how to do), but I can't figure out, how to make it with limitation. Need some padding from top and also if there is collision with one of four sides (left, right, top (here is the padding) and bottom of device) stop the drag and you can't over - or 1px padding like on the top, whatever. :)

I tried this one: https://github.com/andreamazz/UIView-draggable but if I set the area with limitation via cagingArea, iPad (Air) is lagged. Also the moving is not smooth, I think the native PanGestureRecognizer is the best, need just the limitation area, do you know how I can do that please? :)

I'm writing in Swift. And also found some related topics, like this one -> [Use UIPanGestureRecognizer to drag UIView inside limited area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938135/use-uipangesturerecognizer-to-drag-uiview-inside-limited-area) but I don't know what `insideDraggableArea` doing?..

Thank you so much programmers!

Comment: The link has been edited, it checks that the view been dragged is inside some bounds. Witch in your case, padding top, left... etc.

`static func insideDraggableArea(point : CGPoint) -> Bool {
    return point.x > 50 && point.x < 200 &&
           point.y > 20 && point.y < 400
}`

Comment: Thank you Lucho, the example works now, is not useful. Lagged so much. I'm trying on my iPad Air. I think, that's because every frame the code checking all the positions and the condition, right? I need find some smooth - solution that works normally.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem that I faced in my project,
Try this,

1) Init PanGesture

```
let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
```

2) Add PanGesture to your UIView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
....
....
panRec.addTarget(self, action: "draggedView:")
yourview.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)
yourview.userInteractionEnabled = true
....
....
}
```

3) Set your limitation on draggedView function

```
func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        println("panning")

        var translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

        println("the translation x:\(translation.x) & y:\(translation.y)")

        //sender.view.
        var tmp=sender.view?.center.x  //x translation
        var tmp1=sender.view?.center.y //y translation

        //set limitation for x and y origin
        if(translation.x <= 100 && translation.y <= 50 )
         {
        sender.view?.center=CGPointMake(tmp!+translation.x, tmp1!+translation.y)
         sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
         }
}
```

Comment: Man, thank you, but your example not working. The one, in the link in my post on another topic, is fine and working well from the code side. But on real device is it not useful. Lot of lagging there, because every frame the app recounting the if condition, if is there collision between the limitation and the draggable view. :/

Anyone know, how to do it smooth and useful for production build? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Vlastimil,First Set correct limitation in draggedView func then check else remove if(translation.x <= 100 && translation.y <= 50 ) condition, bcos above code that i used in my project its working for me... :)

Comment: Guys, can you record video how it works for you? Because with my iPad is not good. :(

Comment: @VlastimilFiser, Can you able to show what problem that you faced in your iPad

Comment: @ManikandanD Yes, this one (what is on the video) working good, because there is check for the translate. But if I need allow normally drag (all directions, without limitation) in some area and if there is collision with the border of area (can be specified by numbers in code, whatever, of course) the draggable element need be stopped. But the draggable element must be allowed drag back into the right area.

Comment: @ManikandanD  If I change in your code this one `if(translation.x <= 100 && translation.y <= 50 )` to `if(tmp <= 100 && tmp1 <= 50 )` this one is not working well, yes, the draggable element stop, if there is the condition is true, but I can't drag it back into the right area. I need the limitations just like a "padding". The customers can't drag the elements over the screen. This is what I need... Do you know how figure out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use UIPanGestureRecognizer ?
add view to a viewcontroller and check user interaction enabled.
i think you should tag view and use touchesMoved method.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
        if touch.view.tag == 2 {
            if self.yourView.center.y <= CGFloat(230) { //if you want use limitation drag

                var touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)
                self.yourView.center.y = touchLocation.y
                self.yourView.center.x = touchLocation.x
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nahit, thank you. This one not working for me. I have set tag for the view I'm dragging etc. but nothing happen.

Comment: sorry auto-complete problem, i hope this should be work

Comment: its lagging, after adding condition

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
guard let view = UIApplication.shared.windows.last else { return }
view.addSubview(customView)
```