# Limit view movement with UIPanGestureRecogniser

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uipangesturerecognizer

I've got this function that handles the pan gesture on one of my views.

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)


        if let view = recognizer.view {

            view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x,
                y:view.center.y + translation.y)
            }

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)


}
```

How can I make the view stop after it has been moved a specified distance upward(or downward)?

Comment: Save the starting point in an instance property, then after each movement, measure the distance between the currently calculated new point and the original point.  If it's absolute value is greater than 10 in the y direction, stop moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem that I faced in my project,
Try this,

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        //set limitation for x and y origin
        if(translation.x <= 100 && translation.y <= 50 )
        {

            if let view = recognizer.view {
                      view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x,
                      y:view.center.y + translation.y)
            }
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
        } 
 }
```

Comment: If you have any doubt pls ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991808/how-to-allow-drag-uiview-pangesture-just-in-some-area/31994594#31994594

Comment: Alright, the problem is that translation.y only stores values for the current drag, and doesn't store the total values for the translation. @Manikandan D