# Set limit to draggable item in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, imageview, textfield

I have one imageview and a textfield on that image. I make the textfield draggable with below code but it can be draggable to anywhere in the screen. I want that textfield draggable only in limit of imageview. If I uncomment if check in the draagedView function, textfield stuck at the left side of imageview because their x values become same.

I found this solution but can't modify it to work on my project.
[Use UIPanGestureRecognizer to drag UIView inside limited area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938135/use-uipangesturerecognizer-to-drag-uiview-inside-limited-area/31994654)

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.draggedView(_:)))
    bottomTextField.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    bottomTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
  func userDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let loc = gesture.location(in: self.view)
    self.bottomTextField.center = loc
}
func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let compare = MyimageView.frame.maxX <= bottomTextField.frame.maxX
    //if(MyimageView.frame.minX <= bottomTextField.frame.minX && compare )
    // {
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sender.view!)
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    // }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that you are checking the position **before** you do the translation. That means that the text field ends up in an invalid position, after which the `if` block is never reached.

This is a slightly different way to approach the problem and means that the text field reaches right to the edges of the limit:

```
func draggedView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

  guard let senderView = sender.view else {
    return
  }

  var translation = sender.translation(in: view)

  translation.x = max(translation.x, MyimageView.frame.minX - bottomTextField.frame.minX)
  translation.x = min(translation.x, MyimageView.frame.maxX - bottomTextField.frame.maxX)

  translation.y = max(translation.y, MyimageView.frame.minY - bottomTextField.frame.minY)
  translation.y = min(translation.y, MyimageView.frame.maxY - bottomTextField.frame.maxY)

  senderView.center = CGPoint(x: senderView.center.x + translation.x, y: senderView.center.y + translation.y)
  sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
  view.bringSubview(toFront: senderView)
}
```

I have also made it a bit safer by adding a `guard` statement at the top and removing the force unwraps.

Comment: When I change the position of the textfield and make a change, textfield goes to centre of the image view again. I want that to stay where it is. How can I solve that? Thank You!

Comment: It might be autolayout constraints overriding your translation. I would raise this as a new question.

Comment: @EmreÖnder: Remove this code "view.bringSubview(toFront: senderView)", it will work..

Comment: bravo! Much appreciated